# Can you create a powerful magnetic field out of confined circulating electrons only?

Tags: electromagnetism

Would it be possible, regardless of how efficient it was to do something like this, or why you would actually do it, to generate a really powerful magnetic field simply by producing a cycling electric current with lots and lots of electrons, without any actual physical medium like a superconductor material that you would normally run the current through? I know that this sounds similar to particle accelerators and/or superconductors, but that isn't quite what I am imagining.

If you were out in near-vacuum of space and you could set up a loop where electrons whipped around very quickly, most likely under the influence of an external magnetic field that directed this, would the electrons on their own be able to generate a magnetic field, or would you need a magnet or a core material, as in an electromagnet, to activate or amplify the magnetic field somehow?

If you were able to collect enough electrons to be equivalent to say, the mass of the Earth, and you had a very large energy source, like the Sun, or a neutron star, that emitted a powerful enough magnetic field that you could somehow attenuate or direct, could you create a very powerful magnetic field that way?

Answer (score 1):

> If you were out in near-vacuum of space and you could s*et up a loop where electrons whipped around very quickly,* most likely under the influence of an external magnetic field that directed this, would the electrons on their own be able to generate a magnetic field, or would you need a magnet or a core material, as in an electromagnet, to activate or amplify the magnetic field somehow?

Italics mine.

The electrons  can be in  a circular orbit due to a [magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) which has to be continuously supplied.

The well known Bq/v=mv^2/r trajectory.

Their orbit cannot be self sustained. The minute the external field is stopped the electrons will follow a straight line.

As pointed out in the comments electrons can be manipulated in a medium , which is how [electromagnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet) work.

Self sustained magnetic fields exist in plasmas, called [magnetic cosmic plasmas.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_plasma) because they have been observed in the interstellar space and are studied in models of the sun.  It is a whole field of study and research as one discovers by a search on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Any current (flow of charges) produces a magnetic field, ragardless of if it is in a medium or not.
$$\oint \vec B \cdot d \vec s = \mu_0 I$$
where $\vec B$ is the magnetic field and $I$ is the current. If the electrons are flying in a straight line, the magnetic field will be concentric circles around the current, like this:

[image]

At any point in space, you therefore have a magnetic field that is perpendicular to the current flow.
To get a field similar to a bar magnet, you need a loop, and as you said already, without a conductor, you need a magnetic field to deflect the electrons.

That said, you can of course amplify the magnetic field by using an iron core for example. This basically just changes the value of $\mu_0$ to $\mu_r \mu_0$ and you end up with a stronger magnetic field. However, there still *is* a magnetic field even without that core ($\mu_0 \neq 0$).

About the question of the neutron star...I'm not sure why you would want to take the detour with the electrons if you say that object creates a magnetic field anyway. Also, consider that static magnetic fields drop with $\frac{1}{r}$ from a source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the information - I only mentioned the neutron star as a potential 'energy or control' source for directing the electrons; of course as you say it already has a magnetic field, I shouldn't have confused the issue. Can you describe in a bit more detail, when you say "If the electrons are flying in a straight line, the magnetic field will be concentric circles around the current" - do you mean in a spiral around the entire 'line' of electrons, or around each individual electron orthogonal to it; how could I visualise it?

Comment: You can actually do a simple experiment to visualize it: get a wire, hang it up over a table in a straight horizontal line and let some current flow through. Now, place a compass underneath it. You will find that the compass does not align with the wire, but instead always points at right angles to it. You can now try to follow one of the field lines by moving the compass in the direction it's pointing (in 3 dimensions): you'll find that magnetic field lines form closed circles around the conductor. Quite the opposite of electric field lines, they start and end at charges

Comment: Ahh, thanks very much for the clarification on that, I can visualise it now. On a general note, is there anything inherently inefficient or implausible about the above setup versus more traditional magnetic sources (superconduction, magnetars, electromagnets et cetera)? Is there any inherent benefit to confined vs unconfined, electrons on their own versus through a medium?

Comment: Charges in a conductor follow the conductor without an external magnetic field. That is probably a great advantage. With free electrons, the only deflections would come from external electric and magnetic fields. The fields are the same of course, but it is arguably more practical to use conductors and insulators to control the flow of electrons rather than external, macroscopic fields. I dont see exactly where the advantage would be in your setup compared to a simple wire loop.

Comment: If I had the requisite reputation I'd upvote your answer, thanks very much for your help! I was having a strange idea where you could potentially use separate electron loops to direct and control each other free from any materials or magnets, but I'd imagine the physics and calculations of that would be extraordinarily difficult. A sort of electron clockwork that you could attenuate from the outside to generate controlled magnetic fields without requiring a physical setup. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: How would you manipulate those loops? You'd probably need an external field again. Also, stray fields and interaction with matter will make this very difficult

Comment: I was thinking of whether or not you could in effect use a complicated series of electron loops to mimic a physical 'computer' with the preprogrammed ability to interact with an external physical situation in a predictable way, for instance if this construct was in space and it came into contact with a stray helium atom it would do xyz with it. The electron loops would regulate each other with their emitted magnetic fields to keep each other in check without an 'external' source required, or you could interact with it from outside to direct it. Just a strange idea I had :)

Comment: Would Lenz's law actually prevent something like this from working, I am not talking about perpetual energy or anything like that, but if it were designed properly, so that all of the magnetic fields lined up, would the 'machine' stop working, or would it just continue rotating around, losing a bit of energy of course, but not stopping immediately? Could you design it so that the induced magnetic fields keep each other going in a cycle, not gaining energy, but not losing it all either?

Comment: Alright. If we imagine a superconducting wire loop that has a current in it, this will create a magnetic field in one direction (right-hand rule). Another loop in that field will have a current induced by Faraday's law of induction; the direction of that new current however will be such that the mag. field it's creating counteracts the already existing one from loop 1. That is Lenz's law. You'd basically end up with two loops of current, but they wouldn't stop right away, only due to dissipative effects.

Comment: I'm honestly still having some trouble imagining exactly what your setup should look like. Do you think you could make a sketch somehow to clarify this?

Comment: Honestly I am having difficulty imagining how the setup would work myself; I am working through the kinks of it as I go. The best analogy I can come up with is bevel gears, two rotating loops perpendicular to each other, but I am not sure whether or not that would a) work, b) activate or bypass Lenz's law, or c) be the most efficient way to do it; that's why I am trying to really understand the directions of the fields, whether you should use a loop or try straight lines of current, and whether there is an advantage to bypassing magnets and just using electric currents somehow attenuated.

Comment: Using an external field to operate it is not a make or break condition, though it would be preferable if it were 'autonomous' and didn't require an external force, even just to do a single function. I know that it would lose energy, that's fine, I just wonder if the theory of it is at least sound. If you had nothing else to make a computer out of or were trying to imagine how the brain of an alien made only out of hydrogen might work, is it possible to use electric and magnetic fields as gears, in a sense, and representations of positions, even to hold information, or would it not work?

Comment: Ok generalizing it like this, the interactions between those particles are electromagnetic anyway (pretty much), so you are in principle already only using electric and magnetic fields when you are building a classical computer. The great advantage of matter and in specific conductors is, that they put constraints on your current/charges that would be very difficult and unstable to generate with simple fields. There is probably no fundamental problem with such a mechanism, but it would certainly be highly inefficient and hard to realize.

Comment: What you say about matter is quite true, it would be far easier to do something like this with more 'machinery', though there may be upper-limit limitations to it like temperature (and its effect on magnetism, having to cool things and so on) and the field strengths you could generate (if you wanted to make it really powerful), but you are right about that. What do you think the inefficient part of it is, presuming you had really advanced knowledge of physics and the ability to construct such a mechanism, where would it actually fail do you think, is it a Lenz problem, or something else?

Comment: It sounds like an unstable system, so a small variation in some parameter might completely collapse the whole thing. Just speculation, but judging from things like Earnshaw's Theorem, that sounds likely to me.

Comment: Earnshaw's theorem is very interesting, and you're right, it would be unstable. I wonder if you could try something like using a hydrogen plasma reinforced by the magnetic fields that it generates as the magnetic core (a sort of miniaturized tokamak, though there are size limits to that as well, I remember reading); hydrogen is diamagnetic and you could have several of these identical machines linked up with each other and in constant motion around each other. But maybe they would just repulse else other and the whole thing would break apart?

Comment: Maybe :) But do develop that further, maybe it actually has a practical application or gives insights into electrodynamics.

Comment: Thanks, I will; I think it can work, though it may not be useful or efficient, you could even try and trap and recycle (some of) the emitted electromagnetic radiation in the electron loops. I wonder ... anyway, thanks for all of your help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Just saw this. Maybe you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_plasma . Plasma can carry a self sustained magnetic field , the way you try to envisage with electrons. Unfortunately most google entries for magnetic cosmic plasmas are for books.